# High - low number guessing game

Tags: java, beginner, number-guessing-game

I'm learning how to code in Java and I decided to re-write a program made in C++ into Java. All feedback is welcome.

Here is the original prompt:

> This program generates a pseudo-random number between 1 and 100,
>   inclusive. The user will then be presented with opportunities to guess
>   that number. After each guess, the program indicates whether the guess
>   was too high, too low, or correct. The user will bet on each number.
>   Initially, the program will give the user $1000. Each round,the
>   program prompts the user for a bet. The program then prompts for
>   guesses until the user is correct, or has made 6 wrong guesses. Once
>   the round has ended, either by a correct guess or by using up the 6
>   guesses, the program displays the current status and prompts the user
>   to see if he/she wants to play again. This will continue until the
>   user indicates that they do not want to play again or until the player
>   runs out of money.

```
package high_low_game;
import java.util.*;
/**
 *
 * @author mjoseph2017
 */
public class High_low_game {



public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    int money = 1000;
    int min = 1;
    int max = 100;
    int gamesWon = 0;
    int gamesPlayed = 1;
    boolean playAgain = true;
    double percentage = (gamesWon / gamesPlayed) * 100;



    while (playAgain == true)
    {
        printHeading(money, min, max);
        playGame(money, max, min, percentage);
    }

    double winnings;
    winnings = playGame (money, max, min, percentage);

    if (money <= winnings) // compares the money won to amount at the begginning at the game
    {
        gamesWon++; // games won increses if you gain more money
        gamesPlayed++;
    }

    else 
    {
        gamesPlayed++;
    }        



    // prompt user to play again
}

public static int printHeading (int money, int min, int max)
{
    System.out.println("=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-="); 
    System.out.println("Welcome to the High-Low Betting Game"); 
    System.out.println("You have $" + money + " to begin the game"); 
    System.out.println("Valid guess are numbers between " + min + " and " + max); 
    System.out.println("=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=");

    return money;

}

public static int playGame (int money, int max, int min, double percentage)
{
    /*Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int bet = input.nextInt();*/
    int guess = getGuess();

    int bet = getBet(money);

    int numDrawn = drawNum(max, min);


    for (int num = 1; num <= 6; num++) // determines if guess is high, low, or     correct
{
    System.out.print("Guess " + num + ": " + guess);
            System.out.println();

    if (guess > numDrawn)
    {
                System.out.print("Too high...");
    }

    if (guess < numDrawn)
    {
                System.out.print("Too low...");
    }

    if (guess == numDrawn)
    {
                System.out.print("Correct!");
            }

    }
    calcNewMoney(money, bet, guess);
    playAgain(percentage);

    return money;
}

/**
 *
 * @param money
 * @return     
 */
public static int getBet(int money)
{
    System.out.println("Please enter a bet");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int bet = input.nextInt();

    if (bet < 1 || bet > 100)
    {
        System.out.println("That is not a valid bet");
        getBet(money);
    }

    return bet;
}

public static int getGuess ()
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter a guess");
    int guess = input.nextInt();
    return guess;
}

public static int drawNum (int max, int min)
{
    Random rand = new Random();
    int randNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) +1)+ min;

    return randNum;
}

public static int calcNewMoney (int money, int bet, int guess)
{
    int earnings = bet / guess;

    if (guess <= 6)
    {
        money = money + earnings;
    }

    else
    {
        money = money - bet;
    }

    System.out.println("You have won $" + earnings);
    System.out.println("You have $" + money);

    return money;
}

public static boolean playAgain (double percentage)
{
    boolean playAgain = true;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("You have won " + percentage + "% of the games played");

    System.out.println("Would you like to play again? y or n");

    String again = input.nextLine();

    if (again.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
    {
        playAgain = true;
    }

    else if (again.equalsIgnoreCase("n"))
    {
        playAgain = false;
    }

    return playAgain;
  }
}
```

Comment: 1.) format your code with auto-formatting, 2.) fix the error because you had a `semi-colon` aka `;` at the end of your `while` loop which just makes it not work as you would expect.

Comment: Greetings @Heslacher, why do you feel the code is not working, it definitely exists ;)

Comment: @konijn because of at least `double percentage = (gamesWon / gamesPlayed) * 100;`

Comment: You really should fix the `;` at the end of that while.

Comment: A good old division by zero.

Comment: Remove commented code from `playGame`. Fix white space/alignment. Javadoc comments -- use them or don't but don't go halfway.

Comment: I appreciate your vigilance @Heslacher !

Comment: Does the code do what you want respectively what it should do?

Comment: Setting `gamesPlayed` to 1 instead of 0 only to avoid dividing by zero is a bad idea. It is not really a fix, as now you start with 1 played game, before you actually played. That's a bug. Winning your first game will give you 50 % win rate. You should not just change values to avoid errors, but rather check and handle their cause. Set the win rate to infinity when `gamesPlayed` is 0. Furthermore, this was not in your original code, as well as there was originally a wrongly used semicolon after the while-condition. Did the code work, without errors, when you posted the question?

Comment: The original code of the question should not be edited, because editing code based on other users' answers and comments makes them obsolete and outdated.

Answer (score 10):

In the first place, you have this code:

```
if (money <= winnings) // compares the money won to amount at the beginning at the game
{
    gamesWon++; // games won increases if you gain more money
    gamesPlayed++;
}

else 
{
    gamesPlayed++;
}
```

This is redundant.  You should do this instead, which also shows what happens better:

```
gamesPlayed++; // increment gamesPlayed

if (money <= winnings) // increment gamesWon if winnings is <= money
{
    gamesWon++; // increment gamesWon
}
```

Additionally, your code formatting is awful.  You should really format your code so all the levels of indentation are indented the same amount; this will really increase readability.

Answer (score 10):

**BUG and unexpected results**

- Your code does can't escape this loop, unless you are hitting `STRG + C`

  ```
  while (playAgain == true)
  {
      printHeading(money, min, max);
      playGame(money, max, min, percentage);
  }
  ```

  because `playAgain` is never changed. But let us assume this loop wouldn't stay like it  is, the user would be **forced** to play the game again, if he wants to or not.

  > ```
  > winnings = playGame (money, max, min, percentage);
  > ```
- From the assignment

  > After each guess, the program indicates whether the guess was too
  >   high, too low, or correct. The user will bet on each number.
  >   Initially, the program will give the user $1000. Each round,the
  >   program prompts the user for a bet.

  Your code just don't ask after a incorrect guess for the next number. It just compares 6 times the given number to the guessed one.

  Pst, I will tell you a secret: the numbers don't change , they stay the same.
- The `playAgain()` method will evaluate any input which isn't `"n"` to `true`.

**SRP**

At least inside the `getBet()` method you are vialoating the [Single responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)

> ```
> public static int getBet(int money)
> {
>     System.out.println("Please enter a bet");
>     Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
>     int bet = input.nextInt();
>
>     if (bet < 1 || bet > 100)
>     {
>         System.out.println("That is not a valid bet");
>         getBet(money);
>     }
>
>     return bet;
> }
> ```

this method is just doing to much. It is printing to the console, reading from `System.in` and validating the read input and by entering an invalid input, this is done recursively.

**General**

- a condition like `(playAgain == true)` can be expressed by just `(playAgain)` and if you need to check if it is false, you should use the Not operator `!` like `(!playAgain)`
- assigning a `int` to a `double` variable is bad practice.
- comments should describe **why** something is done. **What** is done should be described by the code itself, by using meaningful class, method, and varaibles names.
- dead code should be deleted.
- if you only need `java.util.Random` and `java.util.Scanner` you shouldn't import `java.util.*`
- you have waaayyyy to many new lines and your indention is totally crap.
- the preffered way for placing opening braces `{` is on the same line like

  ```
  if (condition) {

  }
  ```
- classes shouldn't be named using `snake_case` casing.
- a `if` statmenet like

  ```
  boolean b;
  if (condition) {
      b = true;
  }
  else if (!condition) {
      b = false;
  }
  ```

  can be expressed like

  ```
  boolean b = condition;
  ```
- the input parameter `money` in the `getBet()` method isn't used at all.
- variable and class names should not be shortened as this would remove readability
- a `Random` should be created once and reused

**Now, let us get this bugs out of the way.**

But let us do this in the right way. We will use only `static main()` method and only to start the game.

First we add some class level variables which will hold the lowest and highest number which we make `final` as they won't change for a game. We will use constructor chaining, that means we are calling another constructor of the class form a constructor.

So our base will look like

```
public class HighLowGame {

    private final int minNumber;
    private final int maxNumber;
    private final int minBet;
    private final int maxBet;

    public HighLowGame() {
        this(1, 100, 1, 100);
    }
    public HighLowGame(int minNumber, int maxNumber) {
        this(minNumber, maxNumber, 1, 100);
    }
    public HighLowGame(int minNumber, int maxNumber, int minBet, int maxBet) {
        this.minNumber = minNumber;
        this.maxNumber = maxNumber;
        this.minBet = minBet;
        this.maxBet = maxBet;
    }

    public void play() {
        int money = initialMoney;
        boolean playAgain = true;

        while (playAgain) {
            money = play(money);
            playAgain = (money != 0) && shouldContinue();
        }
        writeOutput("Thanks for playing. Bye.");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        HighLowGame game = new HighLowGame();
        game.play();
    }

    private boolean shouldContinue() {
        return readInput("Would you like to play again? y or n").equalsIgnoreCase("y");
    }

    private String readInput(String message) {

        writeOutput(message);

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        return input.nextLine();
    }

    private void writeOutput(String message){
        System.out.println(message);
    }
}
```

now we need to add code for `play()` but before we will change the `drawNum()` method to

```
private final Random random = new Random();
public int drawNumber() {
    return random.nextInt((maxNumber - minNumber) + 1) + minNumber;
}
```

and the `getBet()` method to

```
private final String bettingMessage = "Please enter a bet";
private final String bettingInvalidMessage = "That is not a valid bet";

public int getBet(int money) {
    int bet = readIntInput(bettingMessage);
    while (!isBetValid(bet, money)) {
        writeOutput(bettingInvalidMessage);
        bet = readIntInput(bettingMessage);
    }
    return bet;
}

private boolean isBetValid(int bet, int money) {
    return (bet >= minBet && bet <= maxBet && bet <= money);
}
```

you need to change the `getGuess()` method accordingly.

Here is the entry method for the class.

```
public void play() {
    int money = initialMoney;
    int playedGames = 0;
    boolean playAgain = true;

    while (playAgain) {
        playedGames += 1;
        money = play(money);
        writeOutput("You have played " + playedGames + " and you have $ " + money + " left");
        playAgain = shouldContinue();
    }
    writeOutput("Thanks for playing. Bye.");
}
```

and the overloaded `play()` method

```
public int play(int money) {

    int playedRounds = 1;
    int currentBet = getBet(money);
    int numberToGuess = drawNumber();

    while (playedRounds <= maxRounds) {
        int guessedNumber = getGuess();

        writeOutput("Guess " + playedRounds + ": " + guessedNumber);

        if (guessedNumber == numberToGuess) {
            writeOutput("Correct!");
            break;
        }

        if (guessedNumber > numberToGuess) {
            writeOutput("Too high...");
        } else {
            writeOutput("Too low...");
        }
        playedRounds += 1;
    }

    writeOutput("The number to guess had been: " + numberToGuess)
    return money - currentBet;
}
```

You need to add some exception handling for the case that the user doesn't input numbers when he is supposed to do.

Answer (score 6):

You asked just for improvements, so there's one: change the `printHeading` function type to void since you don't need any return.

```
public static int printHeading(int money, int min, int max) //change int to void
{
    System.out.println("=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=");
    System.out.println("Welcome to the High-Low Betting Game");
    System.out.println("You have $" + money + " to begin the game");
    System.out.println("Valid guess are numbers between " + min + " and " + max);
    System.out.println("=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=");

    return money; // remove this line

}
```

It will work better this way:

```
public static void printHeading(int money, int min, int max){
    System.out.println("=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=");
    System.out.println("Welcome to the High-Low Betting Game");
    System.out.println("You have $" + money + " to begin the game");
    System.out.println("Valid guess are numbers between " + min + " and " + max);
    System.out.println("=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=");

}
```

Here's another:

Move the definition of double winnings to start of main method, and use

```
winnings = playGame(money, max, min, percentage);
```

only inside of the `while` loop instead of `playGame()`.